# How to display nextpage automatically in certain time (10 sec) in php?

Tags: php

I have numbers of pages with data . I want to show that next page of current page automatically in 10 sec and now i have 2 link for next and back. But i want to show it automatically. If the page count comes to last page then it will show the first page.

```
for ($counterstart=$startcounter ;
    $counterstart<=count($device)-1;$counterstart++){
    $entry = $device[$counterstart] ;     
    echo "page";    
}

if ($startcounter ==$result ){
    echo " Back ";
}else{
   echo "Next";
}
```

Comment: use ajax to achieve such result

Comment: i have not such idea about ajax

Comment: please share your html where you are displaying record

Comment: Can i show it by loop  with sleep()

Comment: yes, but that won't have the result you would like to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do via `<meta>` http-equiv Attribute as below augment content with time and next page URL

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;http://www.metatags.info/meta_http_equiv">
</head>
```

Reference - http://www.metatags.info/meta_http_equiv

[JSFifddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramratangupta/r3v5bse5/)

Comment: Interesting! He would need to do something like: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;http://www.example.com/page.php?nextPageId=2">` and for each new page set `nextPageId` to the next page.

Comment: thanks   Ramratan Gupta  and CodeiSir ... this is exact answer ....i only copy and paste it....

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this on the server side*. Use JavaScript: timeouts and Ajax in the Webpage to pull new content.

Searching for these Keywords will take you to a tons of examples and tutorials each.

(*) *or at least it is very complicated*

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout will help you to execute any javascript code based on time you set.

syntax

```
setTimeout(code,millisec,lang)
```

Usage,

```
setTimeout(nextPageFunction,10000);
```

For More Details, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Inside function you can do something like this

```
document.getElementById("NextPageButton").click();
```

Comment: Don't use string in setTimout, It's eval  Use an inline function or just the name of a function.

Comment: @CodeiSir I didn't quite get you. Can you please enlighten me elaborately

Comment: @CodeiSir Understood and Rectified.